# Что означает выражение "поднять себя за шнурки"?

Tags: фразеология, лексика

Что означает выражение *поднять себя за шнурки*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку поднять себя за шнурки невозможно, то оно и означает "сделать невозможное". А вовсе не "пытаться".

Например: *Он "поднял себя за шнурки" и все-таки попал в команду.*

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, это выражение значит "безуспешно делать что-либо; пытаться сделать невозможное", равно как и более частотное *поднять себя за волосы*.

Вот интересная физическая статья, где рассказывается, почему невозможно поднять себя за волосы: http://kvant.mccme.ru/1977/05/mozhno_li_podnyat_sebya_za_vol.htm. Она как раз подтверждает абсурдность выражения.

Некоторые цитаты:

> Вы можете обнаружить, что это всё равно что пытаться поднять себя за шнурки собственных ботинок. *[("К черту ум!" Рам Цзы)](https://books.google.ru/books?id=rTWBAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT92&lpg=PT92&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=iBhbU5ry5U&sig=pGAOAj48u7BTHS7r2_PEWYlMS20&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih3vLFkuDRAhXmYZoKHRS4Bh0Q6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=false)*
>
> — Вы утверждаете, что человек может поднять себя за волосы?
>   — Обязательно! Каждый здравомыслящий человек просто обязан время от времени это делать! *[("Тот самый Мюнхгаузен")](http://citaty.socratify.net/tot-samyi-miunkhgauzen/54249)*

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего это частичная калька с английского to boot - закружать, поднимать (наладить), имеющее омоним со значением  "шнурок". То есть в английском "шнурок" в некотором смысле является устройством для поднятия. И это не ирония.

К сожалению, в русском выражение не столь частое, чтобы однозначно охарактеризовать его как ироническое или, наоборот, серьезное.

(+)
В качестве доказательства английской предыстории.

> Вопросы Ученого Кота, 1999 г. Сентябрь 1999.. Вопрос 8
>
> Вопрос 8: В 1948 году начальник Управления по определению потребностей
>   в вооружении США выразился об этом так: "...Идея его —
>   необоснованна... Это все равно, что пытаться поднять самого себя за
>   шнурки ботинок". О чем же так высказался недальновидный чиновник?
>
> Ответ: О вертолете.
>
> Источник(и): "Техника — молодежи", No6, 1995.
>
> Авторы: Борис Мандель, Норильск

http://db.chgk.info/question/smcat99.9/8

Я слышал об этой истории еще с института, к сожалению, английской версии не обнаружил. Но если принять на веру, то высказывание не ироническое, оно реально характеризует что-то невозможное.

Answer (score 0):

тут скорее дословный перевод английской идиомы pull yourself up by your bootstraps - "достигнуть чего-то (в жизни/в бизнесе) без посторонней помощи", но без контекста сложно сказать точно.